# Plotly - Slider grouping by date

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-python

So I have a table with 3 columns: delay, tips_value and date

Here is what it looks like:

```
+------------+----------+----------+
|    delay   |tips_value|      date|
+------------+----------+----------+
|  -15 to -30|       2.0|2021-01-01|
|  -15 to -30|       2.0|2021-02-16|
|  -30 to -45|       5.0|2021-01-27|
|  -15 to -30|      10.0|2021-04-05|
|  -15 to -30|       2.0|2021-02-01|
|   00 to  15|       2.0|2021-01-01|
|   00 to  15|       5.0|2021-03-07|
|   75 to  90|       2.0|2021-01-23|
|  -15 to -30|       2.0|2021-02-09|
|  -45 to -60|      10.0|2021-04-18|
+------------+----------+----------+
```

delay is a string with 14 possible values and should be my x-axis
tips_value, my y-axis, has 3 possible values, and I'd like to count() it grouping by delay but limiting this count by a number of days, selected using a slider with 7 days backwards as default.
Therefore I'd like to select how many days worth of data I'm seeing with a slider.

So it would be a graph "tips value by delay" which will change values as I slide the number of days I'm looking at, as my sketch below (tries to) represent

[image: sketch]
I honestly have no idea how I do it, it's easy to see my x = df['delay'] but I don't know how to declare y as it changes.
I'm looking through many examples of slider on plotly but I can't find one that groups and changes data while you slide. Could you guys help, please?

Comment: Are you sure that `pyspark` is the correct tag? Isn't your data probably coming from a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: @werner I'm sorry, you're right. I'll change it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- **slider** is using `dash`
- **callback** to get *days* to dataframe filter and then build **plotly figure**
- my runtime environment is **jupyterlab**, FAQs cover other runtime environments
- *days back* I've coded as from **now**, hence with sample data has set default to 100 days

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import io

# use sample data
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""|    delay   |tips_value|      date|
|  -15 to -30|       2.0|2021-01-01|
|  -15 to -30|       2.0|2021-02-16|
|  -30 to -45|       5.0|2021-01-27|
|  -15 to -30|      10.0|2021-04-05|
|  -15 to -30|       2.0|2021-02-01|
|   00 to  15|       2.0|2021-01-01|
|   00 to  15|       5.0|2021-03-07|
|   75 to  90|       2.0|2021-01-23|
|  -15 to -30|       2.0|2021-02-09|
|  -45 to -60|      10.0|2021-04-18|
"""), sep="\s*\|\s*", engine="python", parse_dates=["date"]).pipe(lambda d: d.drop(columns=[c for c in d.columns if "Unnamed" in c]))

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    dcc.Slider(id='days-slider',min=1,max=400,step=20,value=100,
               marks={1: '1 day',200: '200 days',400: '400 days',},
    ),
    html.Div(id='days-slider-output'),
])
# Define callback to update graph
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('days-slider', 'value')])
def update_figure(days):
    # use slider value to filter data, then structure it to make generating traces simple
    dfc = (df.loc[df["date"].ge(pd.to_datetime("now")-pd.Timedelta(days=days))]
           .groupby(["delay","tips_value"]).count()
           .unstack("tips_value").droplevel(0,axis=1).fillna(0))
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=dfc.index, y=dfc[c], name=c) for c in dfc.columns])
    return fig.update_layout(title=f"{days} days")

# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

[image]